# Get total Amount of the column in AngularJs

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am now working on a project wherein I will need to get the sum of a certain column in a modal table. Yes, it calculates the amount but the decimal point is not included. (e.g I am expecting that the result will be 194,000.26 but the result shows only 193,000.00) so it just means it didn't add the decimal point. Anyone who can help me with my codes ??

Here is my view :

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="model in models  | orderBy: sorting:reverse | filter : filter ">

                    <td>{{jsonDatetotext(model.RequestDate) | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModalContent" data-ng-click="getSelectedPR(model)">
                            {{model.RequestID}}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{model.Number }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.ProgramName }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.FullName }}</td>
                    <td>{{model.PONo}}</td>
                    <td>{{StatusList[model.StatusID] | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td class="totalAmount"><span class="pull-right">{{model.TotalAmount | number:2}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{model.asadsf | lowercase}}</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.Modal Na ni -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="basicModalContent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" id="exportablePRItems">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>

                                        <th>PR #
                                        </th>
                                        <th>Item Description
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Supplier 
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Account
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Currency
                                        </th>

                                        <th>Amount
                                        </th>

                                        <th>(USD) Amount
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody data-ng-repeat="selectedPR in selectedModal.ItemList">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.RequestID}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.PartDesc}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.SupplierID }}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.AccountType}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.CurrName }}</td>
                                        <td data-ng-model="amount" class="amount">{{selectedPR.Amount | number:2}}</td>
                                        <td>{{selectedPR.AmountUSD}}</td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7"><b>Total Amount : </b>{{selectedModal.ItemList | sumbykey : 'Amount' | number:2}} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and here is my angular filter

```
PRApp.filter('sumbykey', function () {
            return function (data, key) {
                if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
                    return 0;
                }

                var sum = 0.00;
                for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
                }

                return sum;
            };

        });
```

Comment: You should not call parseInt function in your filter code, if you don't want the integer result.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try changing `parseInt` to `parseFloat` in your filter?

Comment: Thanks @jared ! I got it now :)